# Symfony Sandbox 1.2 returns a blank page after unpacking into web folder

Tags: apache, model-view-controller, symfony1, sandbox

I have symfony 1.0 running on my Windows XP machine but have recently wanted to try Symfony 1.2.

I unpacked the sandbox and set up a virtual host. The page returned is blank.

http://sf_sandbox/web/ returns a blank page
http://sf_sandbox/web/frontend_dev.php/ returns a blank page

PHP, SQLite, Mysql are all fine.

I tired adding

```
echo "test";
```

to the index.php and it outputs as expected.

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any error in some error log ?

Like Apache's error log ?

Is there any way to enable `error_reporting` with symfony ?

A problem that might cause this is some required PHP extension not being enabled ; for instance, symfony might/does require PDO ; and if it's not enabled, it might cause some troubles.

About that, you can take a look at [this thread](http://forum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/78795/) (solution in the last post).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! PDO was not installed and Symfony does not generate an error.

Go into PHP.ini and make sure PDO is enabled.

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci8.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
```

Comment: I guess we did the same kind of google search ^^ Nice you found out :-)